# Java: Selected rows's index does not changes when sorted

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

I have a Jtable on which I called the method 
`table1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);`. 
So this works on well.
But I also have a methos in my JFrame class which is fired when i push a button. It gets the selected rows indexes using this code 
`int selectedRows[] = this.table1.getSelectedRows();`. 
And displays an edit window for the first row corresponding in the selected interval.

The problem is that if I don't click on column's headers (I mean i don't sorte them at all) my method works perfect. But when I sort the row, the indexes of the rows doesn't seems to change at all - thus resulting an edit window for the old row whicn was initially in that position before making any sort.

I am using JDK 6 could anyonw give ma a tip?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The underlying model does not change order.  Only the view changes.  You can read more about this in [Sun's tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).  You will need to use JTable.convertRowIndexToView() and JTable.convertRowIndexToModel().

Comment: Thanks guys now i can find the correct selected value using `table1.getModel().getValueAt(table1.convertRowIndexToView(selectedRows[i]), 0);`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `convertRowIndexToView(int)` and `convertRowIndexToModel(int)` to convert model (underlying data) indices and view indices.