# TableModel convertRowIndex

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I found similar topics and read this:
[Java: Selected rows's index does not changes when sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657947/java-selected-rowss-index-does-not-changes-when-sorted)

[How to Keep Track of row index when JTable has been sorted by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151850/how-to-keep-track-of-row-index-when-jtable-has-been-sorted-by-the-user)

I use three tables that are in correlation to each other

**KUNDE**.KUNDENNUMMER = **VORGANG**.KUNDENNUMMER
**VORGANG**.ID = **VORGANG_AUGENPAAR**.VORGANG_ID

First I choose my customer in the "masterTable", then the "detailTable" show me all the rows from VORGANG to this customer = OK. (masterTable = list, detailTable = vorgangList)
Now my subTable shows me all the rows from VORGANG_AUGENPAAR to this VORGANG = OK

But I have a logic problem, if I want to insert a new row into subTable. For the insert it is necessary to get the right VORGANG.ID from table "detailTable". In my detailTable the VORGANG.ID is printed out in the right way.

with following code I get the correct ID:

```
    int selectedRowIndex = detailTable.getSelectedRow();
    int selectedColumnIndex = 2;
    //get the correct ID:
    int selectedObject = (int) detailTable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColumnIndex);
    System.out.println( selectedObject + "_correct ID Number" );
```

Then I get this result: "700_correct ID Number"

In the next step I try to convert the detailTable index Row to the correct "vorgangList" Model. But there is something wrong:

```
    //this is wrong
    opticanuova.task.Vorgang vor  = vorgangList.get( detailTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndex));
    System.out.println( vor + "_wrong value" );
```

with the code above I get this result: "opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=450 ]_wrong value"

I made something wrong to convert detailTable Index to vorgangList Index. So please give my your advices. I also tried out following code for testing the index number:

```
            //testing vor index value
    int test2 = (int) detailTable.convertRowIndexToView(selectedRowIndex);
    System.out.println( test2 + "IndexConverted_ToView_test2" );
    int convertedRowAtPoint = detailTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndex);
    System.out.println( convertedRowAtPoint + "IndexConverted_ToModel: false mapped Row" );
```

But I get always the index number of detailTable and not of vorgangList.

---

more detail with example:
I tried to do the answer. **Here is now my code:**

```
    //this sequence get the correct ID:
    int selectedRowIndexInView = detailTable.getSelectedRow();
    int selectedRowIndexInModel = detailTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndexInView);    
    int idColumnIndex = 2;
    int selectedObject = (int) detailTable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndexInModel, idColumnIndex);
    //this is wrong
    opticanuova.task.Vorgang match  = vorgangList.get(detailTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndexInModel));
    //print out:
    System.out.println( selectedRowIndexInView  + " = selectedRowIndexInView " );
    System.out.println( selectedRowIndexInModel  + " = selectedRowIndexInModel " );
    System.out.println( selectedObject + " = selectedObject" );
    System.out.println( vorgangList + " = vorgangLIst" );
    System.out.println( match + " = match" );
```

and this are the results:

```
1 = selectedRowIndexInView 
1 = selectedRowIndexInModel 
700 = selectedObject
[opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=400 ], opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=450 ], opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=550 ], opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=600 ], opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=650 ], opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=700 ]] = vorgangLIst
opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=450 ] = match
```

You see, I have already something wrong. I need to have the same value as stored in "selectedObject" in my "match" variable (700 should be id=700 and not id=450). So please give my further help. Best regards

Comment: You've still not said what vorgangList is. Is it the list which backs up your model? If so, the indices of the list are the same as the indices in the model. So you need `opticanuova.task.Vorgang match  = vorgangList.get(selectedRowIndexInModel);`. As I said already, selectedRowIndexInModel is already an index in the model. So it makes no sense to convert it to the model: `detailTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndexInModel)` makes no sense at all.

Comment: HI, the vorgangList stored all entries from Table my table Vorgang. The jTable "detailTable" filter the table Vorgang by customernumber. So in the "detailTable" is a filtered table. This is the code for vorgangQuery + List      vorgangQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vorgang v");
        vorgangList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : vorgangQuery.getResultList();`

Comment: Sorry but if I add a comment the formating is gone. With this code: "opticanuova.task.Vorgang match = vorgangList.get(selectedRowIndexInModel);" I get also the wrong value. This is the result of match: "opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=550 ] = match". It is index #3 of vorgangList and detailTable. But for the correct value the index #3 in the detailTable have to be the index #4 in vorgangList. Is it possible to make a search within vorgangList for the correct ID Number, and find then the correct index-number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have found the correct solution for my problem. It was necessary to make a loop throw my vorgangList to compare the selected value (ID), and find the correct index number.
`//find selected value`
`int selectedObject = (int) detailTable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndexInModel, idColumnIndex);`
`//find ID:`
`for(int i = 0; i < vorgangList.size(); i++) {`
`Vorgang vorgangs = vorgangList.get(i);`
`if (vorgangs.getId().equals(selectedObject) == true) {`
`System.out.println(vorgangs.getId() + " getId " + vorgangList.get(i));`
`}`

Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

`JTable.getSelectedRow()` returns the *view* index of the selected row. That means that if you sort your table, then select the first row displayed in the table, you'll get `0`. But since the table is sorted, this index is not the index of the selected row in the *model*. To get the corresponding row in the model, you must call `JTable.convertRowIndexToModel()`.

So, the correct sequence to get the ID of the object selected in the detail table is:

```
int selectedRowIndexInView = detailTable.getSelectedRow();
int selectedRowIndexInModel = detailTable.convertRowIndexToModel();
int idColumnIndex = 2;
int selectedObject = 
    (int) detailTable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndexInModel, 
                                            idColumnIndex);
```

Comment: Hi, yes this sequence or my sequence above get the correct ID. But my problem exactly is this:           //this is wrong
        opticanuova.task.Vorgang vor  = vorgangList.get( detailTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndexInModel));
        System.out.println( vor + "get wrong ID Number" ); Because with this script I get: opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=500 ]get wrong ID Number. The correct ID Number e.g. 700. And the ID 700 I get with your script above

Comment: I guess why I get in "selectedRowIndexinView" and "selectedRowIndexInModel" the same Index-Number?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You have an index in the model, and you convert it using `convertRowIndexToModel()`. It's already an index in the model, so you must not convert it a second time. I assume that vorgangList is the list backing your model. To get an element from this list, just use `vorgangList.get(selectedRowIndexInModel)`, where `selectedRowIndexInModel` is initialized as shown in my answer.

Comment: OK, it works if the table is sorted. But my "detailTable" is filtered. It depends on the selected value of the "masterTable". So the "detailTable" contains only value with the same customernumber, but my "vorgangList" Model conatins all datasets. So I have to find the correct index Number within "vorgangList"

Comment: sorry but I am a java newbe. You mean: **opticanuova.task.Vorgang vor  = vorgangList.get(selectedRowIndexInModel);**? With this I get the following: opticanuova.Vorgang[ id=450 ]get wrong ID Number